# How Do I Limit The Number of Characters Entered in an Alert Dialog EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I know how to limit the size through XML (android:maxLength), but I am dynamically creating an alert dialog in code. Is there something similar I can use? (Prefer to have API 10 compatible solution as well)

I am using the alert dialog to prompt the user for a text value to be shown graphically later.

```
public void onClickPosition(View v) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle(R.string.title_Position);
    alert.setMessage(R.string.message_Position);

    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    input.setText(_currentClass.getPosition());
    alert.setView(input);

    alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.option_Okay, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        _currentClass.setPosition(input.getText().toString());
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textPosition);
        textView.setText(_currentClass.getPosition());
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try something like this:

```
InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(MAX_LENGTH);
input.setFilters(FilterArray);
```

Answer (score 10):

You can set the `maxLength` equivalent in code by means of an `InputFilter`. Suppose you'd want the `EditText` to accept a maximum of 20 characters:

```
input.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(20) });
```

Since `setFilters()` accepts an array of filters, you can add more than one. Also, for example, if you'd needed more control over what type of characters should be allowed, you could implement your own filter and pass it in with the array.